# Respond to slack channel message in thread with dialogs

Tags: c#, dialog, botframework, slack

I want to be able to respond in a thread to a message using a dialog. I can accomplish this without using a dialog by creating a reply using the activity and setting the channel data. I am not seeing a way to do this with dialogs.

The bot I am creating needs to be able to respond in thread as it will be a user specific thread, but I want to use dialogs as others on team are not as well versed in C#. I have accomplished this with the reply to initial message and use channel data with the ts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So to do this we need to pull the channel data from slack and grab the ts. We then need to update the Id property of the Conversation to append the ts to the end of the Id using a semicolon. The Conversation is a property on the activity.